# How to know if two transparent images are intersecting on non-transparent area

Tags: javascript, css, html

I've to randomly arrange some images in a box in such a way that their non-transparent area should not overlap. Each image can be randomly resized and rotated.

I don't want to arrange them in masonry grid.

What I can think is to randomly place images in the box. Then find images which are intersecting on multiple ends and adjust them by resizing or rotation.

Other solution I can think is to place images in the box like none of them are intersecting. Now increase their size randomly until they intersect.

Whichever the approach I adopt, How can I know if two images are intersecting on their non-transparent area?

**Sample Result**: Consist 8 boxes. Each box contains 8 images.

[image]

Comment: What do you mean by "non-transparent area"? Are these images non-rectangular? Do they have transparent pixels? How are you arranging them - using JavaScript to set `position: absolute` or are you drawing onto a `<canvas>`? What is "the box" exactly?

Comment: A box is nothing but a div container. However I can switch to canvas if it solves the problem. Position also depends on the solution. If I use masonry approach then `relative` position should work otherwise `absolute`. I've updated the question with sample result.

Comment: Sounds like you just need CSS3's `display: flex`. No JavaScript required at all.

Comment: Can you please give me an example? Because as per my understanding it can help only when we can bound an image in a rectangle box where all the rectangles are not intersecting. Eg check pizza image in sample image

Comment: Oh! I thought each rectangular box represented an image. It looks like you actually want "convex hull" packing - that's a very difficult optimization problem in computer-science. Have fun! If you find a perfect solution you'll win some serious Nobel and ACM prizes :D

Comment: I tried to solve the problem using d3 image cloud. But the problem is to detect if the non-transparent area of 2 images are intersecting.

Comment: Though it is not the solution, I've switched to manual ordering. Here is the result https://funcards.github.io/match-it